# Codeigniter Strip HTML tags from input

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is the best method to strip html tags from the input?

How can i remove the HTML tags while validating the input

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'trim|xss_clean');
```

Do I need to add custom call back method to validation rules?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html), you can add strip_tags directly to `set_rules()`:

> Any native PHP function that accepts one parameter can be used as a rule, like htmlspecialchars, trim, MD5, etc.

So it would probably look like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 
                                  'trim|xss_clean|strip_tags');
```

Answer (score 5):

Blanket filtering over application input is totally bogus. It will mangle potentially-valid input and will not reliably protect from XSS. The only way to be safe from XSS is to correctly escape every text string you interpolate into HTML **at the output stage**, eg. using `htmlspecialchars`.

CodeIgniter's `xss_clean` does a quite amazingly blunt and silly set of string mangling even by the very very low standards of “XSS Protection” tools; you should not use it under any circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to add custom call back
>   method to validation rules?

I think yes, you can also do something like:

```
$stripped = strip_tags($content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 
                                  'trim|strip_tags|xss_clean');
```